# SQL - Number of times each visitor has visited a tool

Tags: mysql, sql, select

We have a MySql table in which we log the date each visitor visits an application. So, at any point in time, the table might look like:

```
| Tool   | Email                | Date     |
|--------+----------------------+----------|
| Tool 1 | boy1@gmail.com       | 03/03/13 |
| Tool 1 | boy2@gmail.com       | 03/05/13 |
| Tool 9 | anotherboy@yahoo.com | 09/01/13 |
| Tool 1 | boy1@gmail.com       | 10/07/12 |
| Tool 2 | boy1@gmail.com       | 01/01/10 |
| Tool 5 | boy2@gmail.com       | 05/04/12 |
| Tool 1 | boy1@gmail.com       | 05/10/13 |
| Tool 1 | boy2@gmail.com       | 09/10/12 |
| Tool 9 | anotherboy@yahoo.com | 10/07/13 |
```

What we want to be able to do is get the number of times each visitor (identified by the Email id) has visited a tool. So, for the above table, what we want to be able to achieve is:

```
| Tool   | Email                | Number of Visits |
|--------+----------------------+------------------|
| Tool 1 | boy1@gmail.com       |                3 |
| Tool 1 | boy2@gmail.com       |                2 |
| Tool 9 | anotherboy@yahoo.com |                2 |
| Tool 2 | boy1@gmail.com       |                1 |
| Tool 5 | boy2@gmail.com       |                1 |
```

I have tried to use the group by clause on the Email column, but that gives me distinct Email ids, which is not what I am looking for. What I really want to be able to do is select distinct Tool - Email pairs and count their occurrence in the table. What is the best way to achieve that? Should I be looking at joins?

Would appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could this be all you need?

```
SELECT Tool, Email, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Tool, Email
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**Result**

```
|   TOOL |                EMAIL | COUNT(*) |
--------------------------------------------
| Tool 1 |       boy1@gmail.com |        3 |
| Tool 1 |       boy2@gmail.com |        2 |
| Tool 9 | anotherboy@yahoo.com |        2 |
| Tool 5 |       boy2@gmail.com |        1 |
| Tool 2 |       boy1@gmail.com |        1 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82458/3)

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`GROUP BY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) statement.

```
SELECT Tool, COUNT(*), Email
FROM table
GROUP BY Tool, Email
```